# Excel sheet as frontend for C# backend server

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# feeder that generates some data and sends them to some sort of frontend. Is there a direct way in which I can receive these data using excel microsoft office ? 
P.S. I do not want to write a code that recieves the data and then writes it into excel sheet. I want to be able to directly get the data from excel itself, as a frontend for my C# backend. Is that ever possible ?!

Comment: Designing an entire front end is a bit big for an SO question. Can you narrow it down to a specific task? If you want to know how to get data out of an Excel sheet, or how to save data in XSL/CSV/XML/etc. format, I can help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick dr. Google search for **WebService calls from Excel** and found the following [article](http://www.webcontinuum.net/ws_4.aspx)

```
Option Explicit
' Excel VBA Function wrapper to call currency conversion Web Service on the web!
Public Function ccyConvert(rsCurrIn As String, rsCurrOut As String, 
                           ByVal vfAmtIn As Single) As Single
    Dim objSClient As MSSOAPLib30.SoapClient30      
   ' Remove the 30 if using an earlier version of SOAP
    Dim fResult As Single

    ' Point the SOAP API to the web service that we want to call...
    Set objSClient = New SoapClient30
    Call objSClient.mssoapinit(
              par_WSDLFile:="http://webcontinuum.net/webservices/ccydemo.wsdl") 

    ' Call the web service 
    fResult = objSClient.calcExcRate(rsCurrIn, rsCurrOut, vfAmtIn)
    Set objSClient = Nothing

    ccyConvert = fResult 
End Function
```

As **Excel** has the possibility to **access data (from different dataSources)** it may be a proper solution to *create a c# WebService* which *delivers* the *requested data*.

Pls note that **this is not my code** - it's just a copy from the mentioned article - so credit goes to the author!

I just thought about another solution. You may consider making your own **C# com component**. Within any **excel VBA code** you are now able to **call any method within your assembly**. Once again mr. google found an [article](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/) describing how to achieve this!

**c# code** for your own com component

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DotNetLibrary
{
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
  public class DotNetClass
  {
    public DotNetClass()
    {
    }
    public string DotNetMethod(string input)
    {
        return "Hello " + input;
    }
  }
}
```

**VBA code** within an excel macro

```
Private Sub TestDotNetCall()
    Dim testClass As New DotNetClass
    ' or do whatever you want with return value
    MsgBox testClass.DotNetMethod(“World”)
End Sub
```

Comment: Another scenario would be posting the data into a database. Writing a macro to retrieve the data should be pretty easy.